# How do you set up neo4j to work with Google Compute Engine?

Tags: python, neo4j, google-compute-engine

I'm wondering how one would get neo4j to work with Google Compute Engine. Has anybody done this? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you go,

### Basic Setup

- Install and setup [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/)
- Install [py2neo](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/)
- Create your GCE Instance (https://console.developers.google.com/project/PROJECT_APPID/compute/instancesAdd) using image (debian-7-wheezy-v20141021, Debian GNU/Linux 7.7 (wheezy) amd64 built on 2014-10-21 or ANY)
- SSH your instance `gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME --zone AVAILABLE_ZONES` --> [AVAILABLE_ZONES](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/zones#available)
- Download and Install `neo4j` in GCE - You may need to install java([Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15543636/687692)) and lsof (Fix: `apt-get install lsof`).

### Configuration for GCE

- [Configure server neo4j](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/server-configuration.html)
- (Optional), Add neo4j [https support](http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/security-server.html#_https_support)
- Whitelist neo4j port 7474 (More on [Networking and Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking))
- Add security **username:password** from [github](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension)

  `gcloud compute firewall-rules create neo4j --network default --allow tcp:7474`

### Play around

- Start neo4j server `./bin/neo4j start`
- Check your running instances @ `http://IP_ADDRESS:7474/`

#### Once `py2neo` Installed and server started, try some pycode to test it

```
>> from py2neo.neo4j import GraphDatabaseService, CypherQuery
>> # Set up a link to the local graph database.
>> # When () left blank defaults to http://localhost:7474/db/data/
>> graph = GraphDatabaseService('http://IP_ADDRESS:7474/db/data/')
>> CypherQuery(graph, "CREATE (n {name:'Example'}) RETURN n;").execute()
```

Above python setup / code, you can use it in GAE as well.

### References

- Check pricing of [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing).
- [py2neo Cookbook](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/cookbook/)
- [Compute Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances)
- [gcloud compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/)

### Edit: Appengine + Neo4j

```
from py2neo import neo4j
GRAPH_DB = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService(
        'http://uname:psswd@localhost:7474/db/data/')
if IS_PROD:
    GRAPH_DB = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService(
        'http://uname:psswd@host:port/db/data/')

def _execute(query):
    """Execute all neo4j queries and return list of Record objects.

    Returns:
      Returns list of Record objects.
    """
    try:
        result = neo4j.CypherQuery(GRAPH_DB, query).execute()
        # logging.info(result.data)
        return result
    except neo4j.CypherError as error:
        logging.error(error.exception)
    except DeadlineExceededError as dead:
        logging.warn(dead)
    except urlfetch_errors.InternalTransientError as tra_error:
        logging.warn(tra_error)
    except httplib.HTTPException as exp:
        logging.warn(exp)
    except neo4j.http.SocketError as soc:
        logging.warn(soc)
```

Comment: How would this compare to using Graph Story?

Comment: Is there a way to run app engine and neo4j in one application locally? What I want to do is fetch app engine datastore entities and create my neo4j graph database using it. I checked app engine documentation where they have specified what all external libraries it supports. Right now, I am running into an issue where my csv stream response is more than 32 MB. Also. can't use Compute Engine. pricing is the issue. I am making too many requests!

Comment: Yes, I am using it with appengine only. I have updated my answer including appengine + neo4j + localhost. Please have a look. Hope that answers your query.

Answer (score 4):

the easiest and the safest way is to use [docker neo4j image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tpires/neo4j/)

and this is [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/installation/google/), to install and deploy on google compute engine