# Is it possible to integrate App Engine and Neo4j on local machine?

Tags: google-app-engine, neo4j

Is there a way to run app engine and neo4j in one application locally? What I want to do is fetch app engine datastore entities and create my neo4j graph database using it. I checked app engine documentation where they have specified what all external libraries it supports. Right now, I am running into an issue where my csv stream response is more than 32 MB. Also, I can't use Compute Engine. Pricing is the issue and I am making too many requests!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set up neo4j to work with Google Compute Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751346/how-do-you-set-up-neo4j-to-work-with-google-compute-engine)

Comment: @stdob-- that is about about compute engine. My question is about specifically about app engine and neo4j only